# Kali startx prompting GUI login after logging in already

Tags: boot, login, kali-linux

I wanted to revert back to logging in by command line and starting the desktop by startx. I disabled gmd3 using `chkconfig --del gdm3` and I was given the traditional way of logging in  which worked successfully, however when I tried `startx` it started the GUI but at the login   and I was asked to log in again. How can I make startx go straight to the desktop after logging in?